# Eigenvectors and their uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra

Can there be more than one solution to a eigenvector?

like if I use the calculator on the matrix below, for the value -2..... I get (-1, 0, 2) ..but can the solution be (1,0,-2)?

the matrix is

```
 2 0 2
 0 1 0 
 2 0 -1
```

and the values are 1, -2 and 3

Comment: Yes, eigenvectors are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Any multiple of an eigenvector to an eigenvalue is also an eigenvector to that eigenvalue. The only eigenvector you can't have is the zero vector. So the answer to your question is: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be more than one eigenvector for a given eigenvalue. In fact, there can be multiple independent eigenvectors for a given eigenvalue, consider the identity matrix for example:

$$ I=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

Then $I\vec{v} = \vec{v}$ for every $\vec{v}$, which means that there are three independent eigenvectors all with eigenvalue one.

---

For your specific example, the second vector $(1,0,-2) = -1 (-1,0,2)$, so it is a scalar multiple of the first vector. In this situation, the result is always an eigenvector. This follows because if $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then for any scalar $b$ we have:

$$Ab\vec{v} = bA\vec{v} = b\lambda \vec{v} = \lambda(b\vec{v})$$